# Building an electrolysis tank and I want to regulate a 1.23V into the tank. Any ideas how?

Tags: voltage-regulator, electrolysis

I am building an electrolysis tank and I need some help.

I am an architectural student and I have no idea how to regulate voltage or what battery would I need.
I want to regulate from the battery into the tank a 1.23V current.

Any ideas how to do this?

[image: This is the design of the electrolysis tank]

Comment: Volts is voltage. Current is amperes.

Comment: What determines the precise voltage you need? Knowing that may help improve the answer.

Comment: Knowing the required current would also be helpful.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: 1.23V is what's required for electrolysis of water.

Comment: Electrolysis tanks are best built with current sources adjusted up to whatever current density (amps per square centimeter) your anodes can reasonably handle beyond what's required to exceed the [overpotential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overpotential)...

Answer (score 5):

What you need is a "voltage regulator".  They come in all shapes, sizes, and values.  1.23V though is a fairly specific voltage, and not an easy one to find.  It's not a "standard" voltage, so the manufacturers don't tend to make that voltage.  It may be possible to find one if you look hard enough though.

However, all is not lost, because there are adjustable voltage regulators available.  These use resistors to set the output voltage, and one of the most commonly used ones, the LM317, will adjust down as low as 1.2V, just below your required voltage.

Adjusting to precisely 1.23V though is going to take some very specific resistor values, so you may find you're having search as hard for those as you would for a fixed regulator of your required value.

Comment: I'm sure Vishay can be persuaded to come up with a few.